# How best to null check in for-in loop?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the best way to check if an Iterable is null in a 'for-in' loop? In a forEach loop, you could simply do this:

```
people?.forEach((person) {
   print(person.name);
});
```

The `?.` will make sure that the loop only runs if `people` isn't null. Is it possible to do that in a nice way in a 'for-in' loop as well? Or do you need to do something like this:

```
if (people != null) {
   for (person in people) {
      print(person.name);
   }
}
```

Note that I'm only using print as an example, the actual work done in the loops would be more complicated and that I want to avoid forEach loops completely.

It seems like there should be a better way, but I can't find any good examples of that.

Comment: if you only want to print the argument then you can write it in one line like this: 
people?.forEach(print);

Comment: The print was only an example :) In reality I want to do more work than that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Maybe a method reference in the .forEach() will do the trick for you?

```
void main() {
  people?.forEach(expensiveFuction);
}

void expensiveFuction(Person p) {
  print(p.name);
}
```

**EDIT:** Another solution might be to provide an empty list, if people is null:

```
for (var p in people ?? []) {
  print(p.name);
}
```

If people evaluates to null, the empty list will be used and no iteration will run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This could be useful in some situations, but I would like to avoid using a forEach loop and splitting up the code like this, if possible.

Comment: Please see my second answer.

Comment: Empty list is great! Cheers :D